# Javascript equivalent for PHP's md5() which will also work with multibyte strings?

Tags: php, javascript, md5, multibyte

**EDIT:** *the script mentioned in the question, and the other script pointed among the answers, both work just fine with multibyte strings - turned out my problem was elsewhere.*

Does anyone know of such implementation? The script at http://phpjs.org/functions/view/469 works well, just not on multibyte strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This implementation](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/) seems to handle UTF-8 strings correctly. If you want to test the demo, make sure you change the encoding of the page to UTF-8 in your browser settings first.

Answer (score 1):

The script you've posted has `str = utf8_encode(str);`.
You should probably remove this line and pass in your Cyrillic as UTF-8.